# How do desktop applications know when data is available on a server?

Tags: sockets, networking, websocket, server-side, long-polling

How do applications know when new data is available on a server?  For example, Facetime or skype knowing when a call is coming in, iMessage knowing when a new text is available, etc.  I know the client is not just continually polling the server over and over again, so how is this done normally?

Comment: They issue a blocking read.

Comment: Does this mean long polling?

Answer (score 0):

Such protocols send a real-time notification to the client telling it what is happening.

Comment: Right, but how is this done?  I have heard about several techniques such as web sockets and long polling.  What is the standard?

Comment: There is no standard.  Every protocol does it in its own unique way that is appropriate for its app.  You want to know specifics, then read the protocol specs for those apps.